# Call PHP file in JavaScript Function for Updating MYSQL Table?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, function

I want to integrate a Java script Slot Machine game into my script.

You can see demo here ;  http://odhyan.com/slot/

And also git hub is here ; https://github.com/odhyan/slot you can see all JS files here.

I created a Point Coloumn in User Table that people can play the game with this Point.

I think this JS Function in slot.js checking if user won the game or lose.

```
function printResult() {
        var res;
        if(win[a.pos] === win[b.pos] && win[a.pos] === win[c.pos]) {
            res = "You Win!";
        } else {
            res = "You Lose";
        }
        $('#result').html(res);
    }
```

[image]

So i want to add +100 Point if user won the bet.

I made this PHP codes Uptading points For userid "1".

```
<?php

mysql_connect ("localhost","username","password") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('slot_machine');
$pointsql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid = 1");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($pointsql))
{
$row['point'] +=100;
$addpoint =  mysql_query("UPDATE user SET point = '{$row['point']}' WHERE userid = 1");
}

?>
```

---

**So how can i call or excute this PHP Codes in JavaScript function if user Win?**

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to trigger a network request from your javascript code to execute your php script server side.  Using jQuery's [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function is an extremely common way to do this abstracting away various browser differences.

```
function printResult() {
    var res;
    if(win[a.pos] === win[b.pos] && win[a.pos] === win[c.pos]) {
        res = "You Win!";
        // Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
        // and remember the jqxhr object for this request
        var jqxhr = $.ajax( "path/to/your.php" )
                       .done(function() { alert("success"); })
                       .fail(function() { alert("error"); })
                       .always(function() { alert("complete"); });
    } else {
        res = "You Lose";
    }
    $('#result').html(res);
}
```

Comment: i think jQuery is already icluded with this code ; <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: But when try with your codes, it gives JS Alert " error " . http://i.imgur.com/Jie9cQ9.jpg

Comment: You are correct!  (Though it's an older version... might be a good idea to update it as it doesn't look like a huge dependent code base here).  Thanks for noting this @JacKy.

Comment: hmm...  did you change "path/to/your.php" to wherever your .php file is hosted?  (Otherwise the "error" alert is exactly what I'd expect ;-) )   You may not need the updated jQuery just for this... not sure what might be causing the freeze without looking at the rest of your app in more detail

Comment: I'm running this on wamp server at my home. So i put .php file into same folder that .js and index file of game. And edit like this ajax( "addpoint.php" ) and try like this "/addpoint.php" but still getting error

Comment: Does your database table increment (indicating the PHP script DID execute)?  I'm pretty rusty on PHP but it doesn't look like that script actually returns any kind of HTTP success status code so jQuery may still interpreting the response (or lack thereof) as an error.

Comment: No they are not incrementing after (won) i got error, i cheked. Also php codes works well when execute itself. Damn.. Actually your solution looks pretty good, at least i'm getting an error :) I Hope you can find what is wrong.

Comment: Ok Jandersen , it works now. I added like this var jqxhr = $.ajax( "localhost/addpoint.php" ) .. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function to trigger an asynchronous request to your PHP file.

```
function printResult() {
    var res;
    if(win[a.pos] === win[b.pos] && win[a.pos] === win[c.pos]) {
        res = "You Win!";
        // Here's the line you need.
        $.post('score.php', {userid: 1}, function(data) {
            alert("Score saved.");
        });
    } else {
        res = "You Lose";
    }
    $('#result').html(res);
}
```

This will send `POST` data to `score.php`, or whichever file you want to send the data to. The PHP file can then access the `userid` sent to it by checking the value of `$_POST['userid']`.

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), `$.post()` is a shortcut for jQuery's `$.ajax()` function that is simplified and has some of its options pre-set. The third argument in `$.post()` is a **callback function,** and the variable `data` will contain whatever is echoed out or printed from `score.php` by the time it's done executing. So, you could use `alert(data)` instead, to see what `score.php` printed out. This is useful for troubleshooting and error handling.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function() {
        $.get("databaseUpdated.php");//or what ever your php file name is with corrct path
        return false;            
    }, 1000);
    });
```

hope this will help you use it in your function

```
function printResult() {
        var res;
        if(win[a.pos] === win[b.pos] && win[a.pos] === win[c.pos]) {
          // if    
            setInterval(function() {
            $.get("databaseUpdated.php");//or what ever your php file name is with corrct path
            return false;            
        }, 1000);

        } else {
            res = "You Lose";
        }
        $('#result').html(res);
    }
```

Comment: where should i add this exactly ?